# REST: Is it considered restful if API sends back two type of response?

Tags: rest, api, restful-architecture

We have stock website and we help buyers connect with the sellers. We are creating API to let buyers push their contact details and get back the seller details. This is transaction and get logged in our database. We have created following API:

The request is POST, the URL looks like:

```
/api/leads
```

The request body looks like:

```
{
  "buyermobile": "9999999999",
  "stockid": "123"
}
```

The response looks like:

```
{
  "sellermobile" : "8888888888",
  "selleraddress": "123 avenue park"
}
```

We have a new requirement, i.e. we need to send back PDF URL (instead of "sellermobile" & "selleraddress"). This PDF URL would contain the seller details in case it comes from one of our client.

We have modified the same API, now the request body looks like:

```
{
  "buyermobile": "9999999999",
  "stockid": "123",
  "ispdf": true
}
```

The response looks like:

```
{
  "sellerdetailspdf" : "https://example.com/sellerdetails-1.pdf",
}
```

Is it RESTFUL to do this? OR we should create separate API for getting response as PDF?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't approach it this way. What happens when you need to add XLS? Do you add "isxls" to the request too?

Things I'd consider:

Use a mime type for content negotiation. Post the same request, and specify in the `Accept` header what you expect back - JSON, PDF, etc. You're then actually getting the report instead of a link to the report, which may or may not be better.

- or -

Include a link in the typical lead response.

```
{
    "sellermobile" : "8888888888",
    "selleraddress": "123 avenue park",
    "_links": {
        "seller-details-pdf": "https://example.com/sellerdetails-1.pdf"
    }
}
```

- or -

Support a query parameter that specifies the type in the response.

- or -

Have a single property that specifies the type in the response, rather than a boolean. Much cleaner to extend when you add new response types.

The first two options have the bonus that you don't require clients to handle multiple response types to a single request. That's not forbidden by any spec, but it's annoying for clients. Try not to annoy the people who you want to pay you. :)

Comment: "mime type for content negotiation" how would it work, i need to consume this api on apps too (android and ios)? any example?

Comment: @sahil Both Android and iOS support setting headers in HTTP POST requests. The expected use of the `Accept` header is documented in the HTTP spec: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.3.2.

Comment: just curious, in this case, server would download the pdf for the client and send back the downloaded pdf in response?

Comment: @sahil Yes, the response to the request would be a PDF, not JSON.

Comment: @EricStein Which option is better if the API returns two different resources (like seller details in JSON or shop details in PDF) instead of different types of a resource?

Comment: @EricStein: Would it be still valid to send back "seller-details-pdf" in the api response if the pdf link content has information about (seller-details i.e.mobile,address+certification provided to the seller). Debate is that, since certification has data other than seller details while Lead api is returning back seller details. Is it restful to send back certification in same api response?

Answer (score 1):

Again the implementation looks good to me, however you could potentially look at breaking the return of the PDF URL to another endpoint maybe something like `api/lead/pdf` that way your request body is the same for `api/lead` and all subsequent endpoints under `/lead`. Allowing your routes and other code to handle small portioned tasks instead of having a route that handles multiple flags and multiple code routes.

Answer (score 0):

That looks good to me - the same type of input should give the same type of response but in your case you have two different types of input - one with the "ispdf" flag and one without. So it's consistent to responds with two different types of response, one with the PDF link and one without.

That's still something you'll want to document but basically it's a correct implementation.

Comment: any rest guide/url link that suggests that for different input, you can return back different response?